# Word for the state of being 2?

Tags: word-choice

If unity is the state of being one and trinity the state of being three, what is the word for the state of being two ?

Comment: Duality is the state of being two.

Comment: If you are talking about age 2, I think the word is *terrible*!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be looking for [duality](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/duality):

> the state or quality of being two or in two parts; dichotomy